# OAuth 2.0 Mailkit "Authentication failed" in MVC, but c# console-app works fine

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, imap, mailkit

Because [Microsoft ends the support for Basic Authentication access for IMAP in Office 365](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/) I try to update our application to use **OAuth 2.0**. We use MailKit in a MVC .Net web-application to access an IMAP mailbox, but I get an error saying **Authentication failed**. However, as a test, I can get it to work in a c# console-application.

The strange thing is:

1. If I copy the access-token I acquired using the console-application and use it in my web-application I can successfully authenticate and read emails. So that part works.
2. The authentication itself seems to be successful in the web-application. Our webapp redirects to the Microsoft login-page, MFA works, I see **successful** audits in Azure A/D and I do get a token in the callback. However, this token gives the **Authentication failed** error by Mailkit.
3. In Azure A/D I see some of these errors between the successful audits, but I'm not sure whether  they are related or not: `Error AADSTS16000 SelectUserAccount - This is an interrupt thrown by Azure AD, which results in UI that allows the user to select from among multiple valid SSO sessions. This error is fairly common and may be returned to the application if prompt=none is specified.`

I already verified that the scope for which I acquire a token is the same for both console and web.

The main difference is that I use `pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)` in the console application to acquire the token, but I use a webclient call with a call-back in the MVC-controller.

Here is my code (MVC):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string clientID = "[client-id here]";
    string clientSecret = "[client-secret here]";
    string redirectUri = "[redirectUri here]";

    AuthorizationServerDescription server = new AuthorizationServerDescription
    {
        AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
        TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
        ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20,
    };

    List<string> scopes = new List<string>
    {
       "email",
       "offline_access",
       "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
    };

    WebServerClient consumer = new WebServerClient(server, clientID, clientSecret);

    OutgoingWebResponse response = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(
    scopes, new Uri(redirectUri));

    return response.AsActionResultMvc5();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Authorized(string code, string state, string session_state)
{
    List<string> scopes = new List<string>
    {
        "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
        "User.Read",
        "offline_access"
    };

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Host", "https://login.microsoftonline.com" },
        { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        { "client_id", "[client-id here]" },
        { "scope", string.Join(" ",scopes) },
        { "code", code },
        { "redirect_uri", [redirectUri here] },
        { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
        { "client_secret", "[client-secret here]" },
        { "state", state },
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);


    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var oathToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OathToken>(jsonString);

    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("[Email here]", oathToken.access_token);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (var client = new ImapClient())
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
            {
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Subject: {message.Subject}");
            }

            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);

            return Content(stringBuilder.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

The error  **Authentication failed** occurs at the line
`await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the scope **"email"**.
We had to remove that. Exactly why, I don't know. It was no problem when used in the console app. Maybe it had to do with the fact we used `pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)` in that.